# covariant derivative and angular variation (do Carmo)

Tags: differential-geometry

[image]

Hi, I wonder why the minus before $\sin\varphi\varphi'$ disappeared. By definition, $Dv/dt$ is the orthogonal projection of $v'$ onto $T_\alpha S$. Hence, one should obtain
$$\langle v',w\rangle=\langle Dv/dt,w\rangle.$$
But it turns out that I missed the negative sign. Why? Does anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, everyone. I think it's typo. Exercise 4 just confirms my assertion. The author does miss the minus sign.